# Textarea TinyMCE Field Not Updated in IE 11

Tags: forms, post, tinymce, internet-explorer-11

For my employer, we use TinyMCE extensively to serve our client base. This is one issue where all browsers work fine, but IE 11 has an issue. I am wondering if someone has insight, or has experienced this as well.

A form that contains one TinyMCE textarea is submitted via a submit button. The server returns a response code of 200. It is posting successfully. Here is the problem: In IE 11, when I enter new text into the textarea and click submit, the new text does not get submitted with the form. However, if I enter new text and click the refresh button in the browser, the dialog box appears that says "Do you want to leave this page or stay on this page?".

I click "Stay on this page." Then I submit the form, and the new text that I previously entered is posted with the form successfully. Why? I looked into the `onbeforeunload` and `beforeunload` javascript events to see what might cause it, but so far have not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use the changelog to narrow down the possible causes:

- Bug where editors wouldn't properly initialize if both `selector` and `mode` were used.
- Bug where editors couldn't be re-initialized if they were externally destroyed.
- Bug where editors wouldn't initialize some times due to event logic not working correctly
- Bug where editor wasn't properly initialized if the `document.domain` is set to the same as the current domain on IE

**References**

- [TinyMCE Changelog](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/changelog/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ajax to update textarea, do cache: false like:

$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                ..........